# WPF UserControl inherited from custom UserControl class not working

Tags: wpf-controls

i am creating a UserControl in WPF but it is not directly inherited from UserControl class. My base class is something as shown below

```
public class MyUserControlBase: UserControl, IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2
{..}
```

Now in my Usercontrol project, i have changed the usercontrol class signature

FROM

```
public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl //This is by default when the project was created.
```

TO

```
public partial class MyUserControl: MyUserControlBase
```

But it is giving error "Partial declarations of 'UI.MyUserControl' must not specify different base classes".

Please suggest what i have to change to make it run.

Answer (score 2):

You also have to change where this control inherits from in the XAML part of your class. Still inheritance in WPF is a bit tricky, see this tutorial on how to get it right: http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.com/2009/09/user-control-inheritance-in-wpf.html